# C# Error when searching for control in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a little problem. First of all, some info:
- On my page, I have an `UpdatePanel` with a button inside it. 
- When you click this button, I generate a new row with dropdown lists. Each time I have to generate a table from scratch, because it resets after the click, so I update `[ViewState]` value and generate as many rows as clicks.
- Outside the panel, I have another button. After clicking this button, I want to collect data from drop-down lists. To do it, I have to get to these controls.

I tried to use function `FindControl()`, but I guess I can't - as far as I know, it does not perform a deep search. This means I have to pass as a parameter the exact container with this control. Because control is inside the table, I should get to the `<td>` value and I can't do that (`<td>` does not have ID - yes, I can add it but `<td>` is also dynamically created. That means I would need to get first to `<td>`, then to my control (guess what - `<tr>` is also created dynamically).

Because I can't use `FindControl` function, I use `FindRecursiveControl` function (code below) The problem is, that this function neither finds anything. Any suggestions about what might be the reason? I added this whole info in case that the reason is for example usage of UpdatePanel and page life cycle.

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID)
    {
        return rootControl;
    }

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn =
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null)
        {
            return controlToReturn;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My usage of this function:

```
string control_id = "parametr" + i;
DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)FindControlRecursive(UpdatePanel1, control_id);
```

Script generating table in UpdatePanel after button click

```
protected void generuj_tabele(int il_klik)
{
    il_par.Text = "Ilość parametrów: " + il_klik.ToString();

    TableRow table_head = new TableRow();
    table_head.Attributes.Add("class", "w3-green");
    Table1.Rows.Add(table_head);

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        table_head.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    Table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "Parametr";
    Table1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text = "Wartość początkowa";
    Table1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text = "Inkrementacja?";
    Table1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text = "Zwiększ o:";
    Table1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text = "Zwiększ co:";

    RootObject obj = (RootObject)Session["get_offer"];

    for (int i = 0; i < il_klik; i++)
    {
        parametr = new DropDownList();
        wartosc = new TextBox();
        inkrementacja = new CheckBox();
        inkrementacja_numer = new TextBox();
        skok = new TextBox();

        //inkrementacja_numer.Enabled = false;
        // skok.Enabled = false;

        inkrementacja_numer.Attributes.Add("Type", "number");
        skok.Attributes.Add("Type", "number");

        //inkrementacja.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler((s, eventarg) => checkbox_change(s, eventarg, i));
        //inkrementacja.AutoPostBack = true;

        //parametr.AutoPostBack = true;

        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(row);

        parametr.EnableViewState = true;
        wartosc.EnableViewState = true;
        inkrementacja.EnableViewState = true;
        inkrementacja_numer.EnableViewState = true;
        skok.EnableViewState = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }

        Table1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[0].Controls.Add(parametr);
        Table1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[1].Controls.Add(wartosc);
        Table1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Controls.Add(inkrementacja);
        Table1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Controls.Add(inkrementacja_numer);
        Table1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[4].Controls.Add(skok);

        if (i == il_klik - 1)
        {
            wystaw_liste(obj);

            Price pr = obj.sellingMode.price;
            parametr.Items.Add(pr.amount.ToString());

            List<Parameter> par = obj.parameters;

            foreach (Parameter p in par)
            {
                List<string> val = p.values;
                if (val.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string v in val)
                    {
                        parametr.Items.Add(v);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string p in parametry_list)
            {
                parametr.Items.Add(p);
            }

            parametry_list.Clear();

        }

        parametry.Add(parametr);
        wartosci.Add(wartosc);
        inkrementacje.Add(inkrementacja);
        inkrementacje_numery.Add(inkrementacja_numer);
        skoki.Add(skok);

        if (i == il_klik - 1)
        {
            Session["v_parametr"] = parametry;
            Session["v_wartosc"] = wartosci;
            Session["v_inkrementacja"] = inkrementacje;
            Session["v_ink_nr"] = inkrementacje_numery;
            Session["v_skok"] = skoki;
        }

        parametr.ID = "parametr" + i;
        wartosc.ID = "wartosc" + i;
        inkrementacja.ID = "inkrementacja" + i;
        inkrementacja_numer.ID = "inkrementacja_numer" + i;
        skok.ID = "skok" + i;
    }
}
```

When I try to check parameters of DropDownList (e.g. SelectedValue) I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Try DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)UpdatePanel1.FindControl(control_id);

Comment: I have tried it already - because control is in a table inside UpdatePanel and FindControl() does not go recursively it fails.

Comment: Use 'as' key word. For example: DropDownList dropDownList = this.Page.FindControl("id of your dropdown") as DropDownList;

Comment: That's not working too. I still can't find this control.